# curl posting data to HTTP/1.1 even with http2 option to APNs

Tags: linux, curl, apple-push-notifications, http2

```
curl  --http2  -i -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' -H "apns-topic: xxxx" -H "authorization: bearer xxxxx"  https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/xxx
```

Curl Version :

```
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 nghttp2/1.25.0-DEV librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

POST:

> POST /3/device/xxxxx HTTP/1.1

Error :

```
@@uUnexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /3/device/xxx
```

If i run simple curl with http2 it works

```
 curl --http2 -I https://nghttp2.org/
    HTTP/2.0 200
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem: `OpenSSL/1.0.1f`

This version of OpenSSL doesn't support ALPN, which is the TLS extension needed to negotiate HTTP/2 with the HTTPS server. You need OpenSSL 1.0.2 or later for this.

Some HTTP/2 servers (like `nghttp2.org`) also allows NPN to be used to negotiate HTTP/2 (as that was originally used for SPDY) - and OpenSSL 1.0.1 supports that! But as browsers have dropped NPN support a while ago, the number of servers that allow this are likely to diminish over time.

Comment: Daniel, installed  OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 version. Still facing he same error where HTTP 1.1 call getting trigger. Any clue ?

Comment: curl also has to be (re-)built with OpenSSL 1.0.2-support, did you do that?

Comment: Daniel, Thanks. I tried to (re-)built and getting error below, any idea ?               
checking for libnghttp2 options with pkg-config... no
configure: error: --with-nghttp2 was specified but could not find libnghttp2 pkg-config file.

Comment: ./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local --with-ssl

Comment: that sounds like an entirely different question, and something you're better off reading curl docs for, or asking about on a curl mailing list perhaps

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I could make it work with python and openssl for now. Curl already i spent quite lot time and no luck so far. Thanks for your support